# WORDPRESS Updating failed. Error message. The response is not a valid JSON response

Tags: json, wordpress, ssl, hosting

today i got some problem with my WordPress page. When I try to update my page, this error happens

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OoVG.png)

**Updating failed. Error message. The response is not a valid  JSON response**

This error happens after I installed ssl certificates

I've change all my wordpress link to https://, but this problem still occurs

Does anyone here have any solution

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the url in wp_options table. 
Easy solution is to dump the SQL and replace the URL, run the SQL to the database. 
You can fix the problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

How have you updated the links?

Because if you changed only the two URLs in the settings, that's not enough.

You must update all the link in the database via plugin or a SQL query (much better solution).

Comment: what plugin should i use?

Comment: WP Migrate DB can be the solution. Even if the SQL way is recommended